# How can I check to make sure that only positive values are in final list?

Tags: list, scheme, racket

My question deals with the the difference of two bags. A bag consists of pairs that include a value and the cardinality of the value. What I am having trouble with is checking whether the pair is valid, and can be added to the final list. For example if I run the following:

```
(diff '((1 5) (2 2) (3 4) (4 8) (5 4)) '((2 3) (4 3) (6 2)))
```

The correct answer should be `((1 5) (3 4) (4 5) (5 4))`
However I am getting `((1 5) (2 -1) (3 4) (4 5) (5 4))`. Any ideas on how to check for the negative cardinalities. Any help would be appreciated.

```
(define (diff bag1 bag2)
  (cond
    ((null? bag1) '())
    ((null? bag2) '())
    ((eq? (car(car bag1)) (car(car bag2))) 
     (cons
      (cons (car(car bag1)) 
            (cons (- (car(cdr(car bag1))) (car(cdr(car bag2)))) '())) (diff (cdr bag1) (cdr bag2))))
    (else
     (cond
       ((member? (car(car bag1)) bag1) (cons (car bag1) (diff (cdr bag1) bag2)))))))

(define (member? x bag)
  (cond
    ((null? bag) #f)
    (else
     (or(eq?(car(car bag)) x) (member? x (cdr bag))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to want to keep only the pairs from bag1 where the cardinality is bigger than the cardinality from the corresponding pair in bag2, you should change your cond clause with the test

```
(eq? (car(car bag1)) (car(car bag2)))
```

to the two clauses

```
((and (eq? (car (car bag1)) (car (car bag2)))
      (> (car (cdr (car bag1))) (car (cdr (car bag2))))) ;; Difference > 0: substract
 (cons
   (cons (car(car bag1)) 
         (cons (- (car(cdr(car bag1))) (car(cdr(car bag2)))) '())) 
   (diff (cdr bag1) (cdr bag2))))
((eq? (car (car bag1)) (car (car bag2)))           ;; Difference then <= 0: skip
 (diff (cdr bag1) (cdr bag2)))
```

Further improvements are also possible.  *e.g.*

```
(else
 (cond
   ((member? (car(car bag1)) bag1) (cons (car bag1) (diff (cdr bag1) bag2)))))))
```

can be simplified to

```
(else 
   (cons (car bag1) (diff (cdr bag1) bag2)))))
```

Comment: Well I want to keep the elements from bag1 that do not have the same value in bag2 since it is bag difference(similar to set difference). However, if bag1 and bag2 have the same value then I want to subtract the cardinality of bag1 from the cardinality of bag2. That is why I am trying to check if the result of the difference is zero or negative.

Comment: and avoid to use car and cdr's. instead, adt is always a better way to readable

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for taking the time to help me with my question.